# UserActivity ReferrerURL is nil

Tags: ios, deep-linking, appdelegate, nsuseractivity

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:userActivity...`

method which handles deep link delegate has userActivity which one of its properties is referrerURL which always is nil
My guess is it should contain the referrer app or website data that launched the deep link.

NSUserActivity docs: [nsuseractivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuseractivity)

referrerURL docs: [referrerurl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuseractivity/2875762-referrerurl)

my question is how can I receive a correct referrerURL and not nil